# Read -> change -> save. Thread safe

Tags: python, google-app-engine, thread-safety

This code should automatically connect players when they enter a game.
But the problem is when two users try to connect at the same time - in this case 2nd user can easily overwrite changes made by 1st user ('room_1' variable).

How could I make it thread safe?

```
def join(userId):
    users = memcache.get('room_1')
    users.append(userId)
    memcache.set('room_1', users)
    return users
```

I'm using Google App Engine (python) and going to implement simple game-server for exchanging peers given by Adobe Stratus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this may work.

```
class Room(db.Model):
    users = db.StringListProperty()

def join(userId):
    def _transaction():
        room = Room.get_by_key_name('room_1')
        if room is None:
            room = Room(key_name = 'room_1', users = [])
        room.users.append(userId)
        room.put()
        return room.users
    return db.run_in_transaction(_transaction)
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you! I did't know about "run_in_transaction" :)

Answer (score 1):

In Memcache, the INCR operation is atomic, and returns the new value incremented. For instance, if a value is set to 0, you can obtain a lock optimistically by incrementing it. If you get by 1, you can safely write a value. If you get back a 2, you should retry the transaction.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/functions.html

Answer (score 0):

You need a [read/write lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writer_lock) on your room lists.

Answer (score 0):

memcache is 'just' a cache, and in its usual guise it's not suitable for an atomic data store, which is what you're trying to use it for. I'd suggest using the GAE datastore instead, which is designed for this sort of issue.

Comment: Yes, but the problem remains if I switch to datastore. GAE can't "read-change-save" in atomic way. The only way to do it is to fetch users, append new user and then put them back to datastore.

Comment: GAE features transactions which are designed to give you the atomicity you need. db.run_in_transaction() should allow you to run your join() function atomically.